# SQL - how to select data on a monthly basis?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following DF :

| Date | Name | NumberID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05-JAN-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 07-JAN-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 09-FEB-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 10-FEB-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 11-FEB-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 12-MAR-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 02-MAR-2022 | Test | 1 |

What would be the SQL Request which would return :

| Date | Name | NumberID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05-JAN-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 09-FEB-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 02-MAR-2022 | Test | 1 |

Note that I can't do a

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1 tb1 WHERE tb1.Date in ('05-JAN-2022','09-FEB-2022',ect..)
```

Because there is a ton of dates and I don't know them.

**More complex example**

| Date | Name | NumberID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05-JAN-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 07-JAN-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 09-FEB-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 10-FEB-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 11-FEB-2022 | Test1 | 1 |
| 12-MAR-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 02-MAR-2022 | Test | 1 |

the output would be :

| Date | Name | NumberID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05-JAN-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 09-FEB-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 11-FEB-2022 | Test1 | 1 |
| 02-MAR-2022 | Test | 1 |

My Query :

```
SELECT 
tc.TITLETest,
MIN(tc.DATETest) AS YOURDATE,
tc.CRSTest
FROM Table tc
WHERE tc.TC= 1 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM YOURDATE),tc.TITLETest,tc.CRSTest
ORDER BY YOURDATE
```

Comment: If you don't the know dates, which is the logic by which we can figure out which dates should be used to filter?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The logic is that I want to take the first date available for each month

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: You should please tag your DMBS because date functions differ a lot between them. And which is the "first"? There is no order in SQL unless you apply one. Do you mean the earliest day per month?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is ORACLE SQL Developer

Comment: @JonasMetzler I have edited tag, Yes I do mean earliest day per month, so im my example its 05 jan 09 feb and 02 mar

Comment: Your sample data is not meaningful or do your whole table looks like this? What to do if name or number id differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can select the earliest date with `MIN` and `GROUP BY` the month:

```
SELECT MIN(yourdate) AS yourdate, name, numberid
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM yourdate), name, numberid
ORDER BY yourdate;
```

Using SQL key words as table name or column name is a bad idea, so the column "date" should be renamed to something more meaningful, for example "sellDate".
This query produces this result for your sample data:

| Yourdate | Name | NumberID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05-JAN-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 09-FEB-2022 | Test | 1 |
| 11-FEB-2022 | Test1 | 1 |
| 02-MAR-2022 | Test | 1 |

Try out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DLLO4Aax)

Comment: Well, if your column name is not "yourdate", you will need to replace "yourdate" by your column name. If your column name is "mygreatDate", you will need to write this also in the query. Same for the table name "yourtable".

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR("Date", 'MON-YYYY')
                                   ORDER BY "Date") rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT "Date", Name, NumberID
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Working for the first example in my post, how do you do for the second example ? I got to select all the first date available for each month for each name ..